# QFileDialog::getOpenFileName returns the full path not the file name

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog, qtwidgets

I'm creating a text editor using QT Widgets, with tabs like VS Code, and when I open a file with `QFileDialog` I want to rename the tab title to the name of the file just like normal text editor do, I've found the `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` but that method returns the full path, and I want to return only the file name. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can easily remove the path for display however you most likely need the path if you are going to open the file.

Comment: but the path format is different for each OS in Unix `/home/user/...` and in Windows `C:\Users\username\...`

Comment: Qt has functions to do this for you.

Comment: Which function ?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#fileName

Comment: Thank you for your help !

Comment: fileName method in the FileInfo interface